# What is the difference between "Digest" and "Compendium"?

Tags: word-difference, translation

My translation, from a Russian text about an environmental rehabilitation project:

> Another important part of this effort was the inclusion of the best practices accumulated by the project in the "**Digest** of Innovative Solutions for the Conservation of Biodiversity in The Coal-Mining Sector.”

An editor changed it to:

> Another important part of this effort was the inclusion of the best practices accumulated by the project in the "**Compendium** of Innovative Solutions for the Conservation of Biodiversity in The Coal-Mining Sector.”

The original Russian word is **[сборник](http://wooordhunt.ru/word/%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)** ([Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)).

I wonder what the difference is between "digest" and "compendium" in this context.

The word **compendium** feels a bit antique to me, and **digest** feels like the "plain vanilla" choice, but maybe I'm wrong!

Comment: **digest** connotes an abridged summary to me, whereas a **compendium** is a collection that doesn't omit essential detail. **compendious** can mean "comprehensive". "compendium" and "innovative" side-by-side *does* seem a bit 18th century.  :)

Comment: The correct choice here would depend on the overall style of the original text. Could you provide the original, Russian paragraph?

Comment: You can go all 17th c. on his ass and call it a **Summulary**.  Get you some alliteration going.

Comment: @Vekzhivi - the document is written in the usual corporate style intended to stress the importance of the work performed and results achieved. I'm not sure I'm free to quote large chunks of the text. I did not sign a non-disclosure agreement, but I did not ask my client whether I'm free to post excerpts either.

Comment: got it. well I don't care much for Compendium, either. It sounds TOO high-brow. How about just Compilation, or Summary?

Comment: I think the choice would depend on what type of publication "...Innovative Solutions for the Conservation of Biodiversity..." is - The most famous "digest" I know of (at least in the US) is [Reader's Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reader's_Digest) which started out as a sampling of articles and book excerpts. I agree with Tᴚoɯɐuo that a "compendium" is more complete than a digest and would likely have a large number of pages and be published at most annually.

Comment: Here's an example of a "compendium" : https://www.ahrq.gov/chsp/compendium/index.html You can see it's published annually and intended to be a comprehensive overview. Another related word would be "Journal". For example: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijbd/